# What will be the output accessing a list on different threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have an `ArrayList` of `String`s and two threads are concurrently accessing the list. 
What will the output of following snippet and why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        list.add("Number" + i);
    }

    new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            for (String s : list) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }.start();

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            list.remove("Number5");
        }
    }.start();

}
```

I tried using the same code making the `Arraylist` synchronized using `Collections.synchronizedList(list)`. It is still throwing `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Do you mean to ask, "Is this function thread safe"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Javadoc of [`synchronizedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-) clearly states that:

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it:
>
> ```
> List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
>  ...
> synchronized (list) {
>     Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>     while (i.hasNext())
>         foo(i.next());
> }
> ```
>
> Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic behavior.

Since in this code you are removing from a `List` while you are iterating over it (in a different thread but it is the same instance of the `List`), a `ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown.

Using `Collections.synchronizedList`, the following code will run fine.

```
final List<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    list.add("Number" + i);
}

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (list) {
            for (String s : list) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}.start();

new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized (list) {
            list.remove("Number5");
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put a lock on the `list` object using [syncrhonized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196723/learning-java-use-of-synchronized-keyword) keyword.

> **Synchronized** Keyword
>    Its overall purpose is to only allow one thread
>   at a time into a particular section of code thus allowing us to
>   protect, for example, variables or data from being corrupted by
>   simultaneous modifications from different threads.

So this should work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...

    new Thread() {

        public void run() {
        synchronized(list){
            for (String s : list) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        }
    }.start();

    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
        synchronized(list){
                    list.remove("Number5");
        }
        }
    }.start();

}
```

---

**NB:** It depends on what logic you want btw. *Do you want remove from the list as you iterate over it or? you want the two tasks to happen sequentially?*

Comment: me too: was looking for the purpose. If required, I guess we will have to interleave the tasks between the two threads. Moreover, adding and removing is similar to a producer-consumer problem, (Printing the whole list requires the lock on whole list object, depending on the intention of the developer.)

Comment: yeah exactly it all depends on the intention of the developer. But the developer is not commenting so.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are `iterating` (in first thread) and `updating` (in second thread) the same `list` object in the two different threads, so there is always (possibility) that it will throw `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

In the java Iterator are fail-fast in nature, so as soon as they realize that underline structure has been changed, they will fail with the `ConcurrentModificationException` exception.

If you want to use the same list object for you needs, you consider synchronizing it, using the `synchronized(list)` in both the threads `run` method.

```
    public void run() {
        synchronized(list) {
          for (String s : list) {
              System.out.println(s);
          }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized(list) {
          list.remove("Number5");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Vector` instead of `ArrayList` for being `ThreadSafe` plus using `Iterator` for browsing your List.